# Matlab error incorrect number of inputs or outputs for function solve

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a simple equation in MatLab but I keep getting this error that says "Incorrect number or types of inputs or outputs for function 'solve'".

Here is my code:

```
syms tau12 sig11 sig22

tau12= 6e6
sig11 =22e6
sig22 = 10e6

solve(tan(2*theta) == tau12 / ((sig11 - sig22) / 2), theta)
```

atan, tand do not work. I think there might be something wrong because I see a matrix.

Comment: You need to define `theta` as symbolic: `syms theta`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that theta isn't a syms variable, so the first argument you're entering into solve isn't an object of class 'eqn'.

Try creating your equation as a separate variable first, like;

```
syms theta
my_eqn = tan(2*theta) == tau12 / ((sig11 - sig22) / 2)
solve(my_eqn, theta)
```

This should help you avoid similar issues in the future, by returning an error when you're creating the eqn object, rather than something more confusing when you're calling solve()